# Processing CSV load and manipulate

Tags: processing

I have the following code:

```
import processing.pdf.*;
Table table;

void setup() {
  size(2000,2000, PDF, "my.pdf");
  background(255);

  table = loadTable("my.csv", "header");

  println(table.getRowCount() + " total rows in table"); 

  for (TableRow row : table.rows()) {

    String ind = row.getString("Individual");
    float value = row.getFloat("Value");

    if (ind == "An") {

      stroke(0);
      noFill();
      ellipse(1000,1000,value,value);
      println("Dracula");

    }

  println("Finished.");
  exit();
}
```

One csv row looks like this:

```
Individual, Value
An, 34.56
```

If I run the above code I get

```
200 total rows in table
Finished.
```

Why does it not extract all the An data and plot it (like I expected it to do) ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it entering the loop at all, or is the IF condition not matching? Try printing something for every line in the loop (before the IF condition). If that outputs 200 times, then you know it's your IF condition that's not evaluating to true

Comment: Well that is exactly why I added println("Dracula"). It does not print Dracula. So it is the if statement, but I know that I have rows with "An" in the csv file. Hope that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Rather than using any fancy debug techniques, you could, for every line print your `ind` contents, make sure its reading and populating that variable correctly. If you see that it is and you see the word "An" only (must be "An" only of course, it won't match partial strings), then it could be non-display characters maybe? Try creating a hash (md5?) to act as a checksum of your ind variable, then see if the computed hash is the same as a pre-computed hash that you know is correct (if using md5, make sure that an md5 hash of your ind variable is equal to `978b697963cfc5abfced8a4b611977c9`).

Comment: Sorry. I think your idea is the fancy one :). I believe for some reason the if statement does not work. I can't understand why. Because it runs through it without an error. But nothing is displayed, printed. Whatever I put in the if statement does not work. I don't believe it is non-display characters, because it works outside of that if statement.  Any other ideas. I am sure it is something simple/stupid I forget. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the checksum idea? How can you say you don't think it's non-display chars if it works outside the IF? If it prints outside the condition, then obviously the IF is failing, so `ind is NOT equal to An` as far as the program is concerned, so non-display chars would be a perfectly reasonable possibility. Maybe try uploading your CSV?

Comment: Found the solution. Coming from Python I thought "==" is what it is in Python. But I learned Java does not work like that and I need if(ind.equals("An")) and everything is fine. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you found the solution, please post an answer to your own question.